# Split a matrix into two sum equal matrices based on value

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, split, size

I want to split this matrix into two matrices such that when I take the sum of the two splitted matrices I need to get my original matrix.

```
Amp =  array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.]])
```

split into:

```
Al =  array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

and:

```
 Ar =  array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Actually, have no idea how to do this since both values are '1' and will always be 1 (or zero).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to use `np.where` that gives you the position of cells that satisfy a specific condition:

```
>>> np.where(Amp==1)
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]), array([0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5]))
```

Since the result is sorted by row, you can fill `A1` and `A2` alternatively.

```
A1 = np.zeros(Amp.shape)
A2 = np.zeros(Amp.shape)
row_index, col_index = np.where(Amp==1)
for ind in range(0, len(row_index), 2):
    A1[row_index[ind], col_index[ind]] = 1
    A2[row_index[ind+1], col_index[ind+1]] = 1
```

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I wanted to do! :)